# Single Sign on for NodeJs application (NTLM-LDAP) possible?

Tags: node.js, active-directory, single-sign-on, ntlm

I have a node application that is on an Active Directory Domain Network.

The clients connecting to the node app will also be on the same network.

I am trying to integrate SSO(Single Sign On) for the clients trying to connect to my Node app (common client browsers: Chrome and Firefox).

I currently have NTLM protocol integrated to my node application, but the users are initially required to enter their AD credentials, I would love to skip that step, but I do not know if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

[node-sspi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sspi) will take care of this. It's able to automatically detect the domain user's account and group permissions if logged in. If non-domain user detected, it will ask for credentials.